# Найти кодоны, соответствующие последовательности цифр идущих друг за другом >=8 (polyQ)

Tags: perl

У меня имеется файл, где указано:

- Колонка 1 - номер последовательности аминокислоты "Q" и кодонов.
- Колонка 2 - последовательность Q.
- Колонка 3 - нуклеотид, соответствующий данной аминокислоте.

Мои кодоны, которые находятся в отрезке polyQ (IN), должны быть в последовательности цифр из первой колонки от 8 и выше , то есть >=8.
Например, певое число в первой колонке = 5
После него идет не 6, 7, 8 и так далее, а идет 16, мы не имеем последовательность цифр, которая равна 8 и выше. -> то есть кодон, находящийся напротив этой цифры 5 - не относится к последовательности polyQ, то есть он OUT

Если посмотрим на число 84, то увидим, что за ним стоит следующее по порядку число 85. То есть наш предел равен 2, так как состоит из двух чисел идущих друг за другом. Но это не соответствует условию, что предел чисел идущих друг за другом равен от 8 и выше, поэтому эти кодоны не лежат в последовательности polyQ.

Если же посмотреть на цифру 89, то мы видим последовательность от 89, то там идет числа по порядку: 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102 -> последовательность чисел ДРУГ ЗА ДРУГОМ, которая больше, чем 8, что соответствует нашему условию, что кодоны, находящиеся в последовательности чисел от 8 и выше, относятся к polyQ -(IN)

Мне нужно написать script, c дополнительной колонной номер 4, где будет указано IN или OUT, в зависимости от того, где лежит этот кодон - в пределе чисел идущих друг за другом равным 8 и выше - IN; или которые не лежат в этом пределе, то есть меньше 8 -OUT.

!!!Тут важна только первая колонка
Значения в колонках 2 и 3 не имеют отношения к решению задачи. А строка 102 - она IN, так как перед ней тоже есть последовательность, которая соответствует условию последовательности чисел от 8 и выше Главное, чтобы это была последовательность, идущих по порядку чисел, а не иммет значения, от 1 до 10 или от 10 до 1

НО!!!!!!! числа не могут повторяться, то есть последовательность, например: 90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98
или же: 125, 124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119, 118

5   Q   CAA
16  Q   CAG
21  Q   CAA
74  Q   CAA
80  Q   CAG
82  Q   CAG
84  Q   CAG
85  Q   CAG
89  Q   CAG
90  Q   CAG
91  Q   CAG
92  Q   CAG
93  Q   CAA
94  Q   CAG
95  Q   CAG
96  Q   CAG
98  Q   CAG
99  Q   CAG
100 Q   CAG
101 Q   CAG
102 Q   CAG
106 Q   CAG
107 Q   CAG
108 Q   CAG
109 Q   CAG
110 Q   CAG
111 Q   CAG
112 Q   CAG
113 Q   CAA
114 Q   CAG
115 Q   CAG
116 Q   CAG
118 Q   CAG
120 Q   CAG
121 Q   CAG
125 Q   CAG
126 Q   CAG
127 Q   CAG
129 Q   CAA
133 Q   CAG
134 Q   CAG
135 Q   CAG
136 Q   CAG
137 Q   CAG
139 Q   CAG
140 Q   CAG
141 Q   CAG
142 Q   CAG
143 Q   CAG
144 Q   CAG
145 Q   CAG
146 Q   CAG
154 Q   CAA
156 Q   CAG
157 Q   CAA
158 Q   CAG
160 Q   CAG
161 Q   CAG
162 Q   CAG
163 Q   CAA

Есть какие-то идеи? Я новичок в PERL, буду очень благодарна.

Comment: P.S. И кстати на этом ресурсе не принято делать всю работу за других, а принято помогать в сложных моментах тем, кто сами уже что то сделали и показали эти попытки в тексте вопроса. Ваш вопрос теоретически может быть закрыт по этой причине как оффтопик "вопрос содержит только текст задачи". Хотя лично мне поставновка вопроса интересна, может и напишу, особенно если первые вопросы проясните

Comment: Так, все любопытственне и любопытственнее ... "_не иммет значения, от 1 до 10 или от 10 до 1_" - это значит, что числа могут идти и задом наперед ? И это значит, что числа могут идти вообще как угодно ... А повторятся они могут, т.е. последовательность `1 2 3 2 3 2 3` может встретится на входе ?

Comment: Да, если ссылки "добавить комментарий" нет или вам пока не дают ей пользоваться. под вопросом есть ссылка "править" можете внести уточнения в сам вопрос !

Comment: @Mike, я просто хочу поставить плюсик, потому что раза три пытался вникнуть в задачу, а ты код написал :)

Answer (score 1):

For Each (N = номер строки списка)

- если Col_1(N+7) = Col_1(N) + 7 *(**UPD:** или = Col_1(N) - 7)*, то Col_4(N) = 'In', иначе
- если Col_4(N-1) = 'In' и Col_1(N-1) = Col_1(N) - 1 *(**UPD:** или = Col_1(N) + 1)*, то Col_4(N) = 'In', иначе
- Col_4(N) = 'Out'

Так что прочитать в массив, пробежаться по нему сверху вниз, заполнив колонку 4, сохранить в файл.

**UPD:** добавлены проверки для случая контроля убывающей прогрессии. То, что (цитата) *числа не могут повторяться*, делает это дополнение достаточным.

Comment: Вы поторопились, числа могут уменьшаться, а не всегда увеличиваться

Comment: @Mike *Вы поторопились* Добавление о возможности убывания чисел сделано позже моего ответа. Но ладно, поправим и для такого случая.

Comment: интересно кто нас всех минусует ... видать не понравилось, что ответ на вопрос без попыток автора :(

Comment: Кстати ваша правка не пройдет... `1 2 30 4 5 6 7 8`

Comment: @Mike как я понимаю, исходные данные - это лог работы секвенатора, а там не может быть таких прыжков... В самом крайнем случае первую проверку можно "размотать" на проверку следующих семи, типа `Col_1(N+i) = Col_1(N) + i * SIGN(Col_1(N+1) - Col_1(N))`

Comment: ну да, я по такому пути и пошел. правда я боюсь, что может оказаться, что `1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8` то же соответствует, если перестановки там в порядке вещей, ТС это не уточняла

Comment: @Mike Последний описанный мной вариант, с проверкой всех 7 последующих, не пропустит вариант с перестановками внутри списка, срежется на пятёрке. PS. А минусует нас скорее всего сама автор вопроса - куда-то её десятка репы же девается...

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;         # <--- Allways use this
use warnings;       # <--- and this
use feature 'say';

my @DATA=map {chomp; $_} <>;  # Загружаем строки со стандартного ввода в массив, убирая переводы кареток
my $i=0;
while($i <= $#DATA) {  # Обходим массив с 0 до последнего элемента
 my $j;
 my $delt=0;
 for($j=$i; $j < $#DATA; $j++) {
   # Выделяем цифры с начала строки в текущем и следующем элменте, получаем разность
   my $d=($DATA[$j]=~/^(\d+)/)[0] - ($DATA[$j+1]=~/^(\d+)/)[0];
   last if abs($d)!= 1;  # Если отличаются более чем на 1 - выходим из цикла
   if( ($delt>=0 && $d>0) || ($delt<=0 && $d<0) ) { # Разница имеет тот же знак, что раньше
     $delt+=$d;   # Накапливаем разницу
   } else {
     last;   # Знак оказался другим - выходим
   }
 }
 if(abs($delt)>=7) {  # Если более 8 элементов (разница будет 7)
   $DATA[$_].=" IN" for $i..$j;  # Добавляем IN во все элементы массива от i до j
   $i=$j+1;  # Следующим будем проверять элемент уже после всех строк с IN
 } else {
   $DATA[$i].=" OUT";  # Нет 8 элементов, пишем OUT
   $i++;
 }
}
say for @DATA;  # Печатаем элементы массива
```